# How to copy selected items from multi-level list to text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a small troubleshooting guide which is created in Jquery and HTML. When user selects a step this is designed to give next step to try and from there next one in a flow chart style.

I wanted to add a selection button so that once user completed a flow of troubleshooting they should be able to copy all selected items to a text box automatically. Can anyone help me with a code which will select all user selected items from the flow and paste / populate them into a text box.

Please find the code I used for the troubleshooting guide. Any help will highly appreciated.. Thanks in advance..

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var count = 0; 
$('#questions').hide(); 
$('#answers').hide(); 
$('#questions tr:nth-child(2)').attr('id','currow');     
var q1 = $('#currow td:nth-child(2)').html();
var q3 = '<div id="d' + count + '"><p>' + q1 + '</p>' ; 
var a1 =  $('#currow td:nth-child(3)').html();
var r1 = q3 + a1 +'</div>';
$('#showquestion').html(r1);

$('li').live('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); 
    var target = $(this).attr('id');
    var parid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var parnum = parseInt(parid.slice(1,3)); 
    count = count + 1;
    var ps = $('#showquestion div').length; 
    $('#showquestion div').each(function() { 
        var divid = $(this).attr('id'); 
        var divnum = parseInt(divid.slice(1,3));
        if(divnum > parnum) 
            $(this).remove()
        }) 
    $('td' ).each(function(){
        var qnum = $(this).text(); 
        if(qnum == target) {
            var q = $(this).next('td').html();
            var q2 = '<div  id="d' + count + ' "><p>' + q + '</p>'; 
            var a = $(this).next('td').next('td').html();
            var qs = $('#showquestion').html();
            var r = qs + q2 + a +'</div>'; 
            $('#showquestion').html(r);
            window.scrollBy(0,400); 
            }
        })
    })
})

<div class="luiTitle"><a href="http://google.com" style=" text-decoration:none;          color:#bbb">Support System </a></div>

<div id="showquestion" class="answers"></div>

<p><a href="TEST1.HTML"title="To my second webpage">Click here to go back to Selection   Page</a></p>

<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="questions" >
<tr>
<td>No</td>
<td>Question/Heading </td>
<td>Answers </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Question 1</td>
<td><ul>
  <li id="2">Option 1</li>
  <li id="3">Option 2</li>
  <li id="4">Option 3</li>

</ul></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Level 2 - from question 1 Option 1</td>
<td><ul>
  <li id="5">Option 1</li>
  <li id="6">Option 2</li>

</ul></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Level 2 - from question 1 - no</td>
<td><ul>
  <li id="9">Option 1</li>
  <li id="10">Option 2</li>
  <li id="6">Option 3</li>
  <li id="7">Option 4</li>
</ul></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>Level 3 - from level 2 option 1</td>
<td><ul>
  <li id="11">Option 1</li>
  <li id="12">Option 2</li>
  <li id="13">Option 3</li>
<li id="13">Option 4</li>
</ul></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document` is an object, when you say `$('document')`, jQuery will try to look for `document` tag on the page. Change that to `$(document).ready()` and try it.

`var parid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');` in this line `this` points to `li` element and `parent` of `parent` will give a `td` which do not have any id, so `parid` will always be null or empty.

Comment: Hi Shankar, Thank you for the suggestion. The above code working perfectly fine what I want is a code which can populate user selected items from the tree view to a text box when user clicks on a button...So that they can copy these steps to a document from the text box.

Comment: Where is the button and what if multiple items are selected? How to show them in the textbox?